# how to fetch a model using the order by of an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I have Models A and B. A has_many B. Now I wanna fetch all the records of A ordered by the B's updated_at. Is it possible to write a find function for this?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
A.find(:all, :include => ['Bs'], :order => 'Bs.updated_at')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of A and B, lets say a Teacher has many Students:

```
teachers = Teacher.joins(:students).order('students.updated_at').uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't makes sense when A has many Bs.

Consider the example:

```
A1 => [B1, B2]
A2 => [B3, B4]
```

Assuming the following:

```
B1.updated_at => 2.days.ago
B2.updated_at => 1.day.ago

B3.updated_at => 4.days.ago
B4.updated_at => 1.days.from_now
```

Now which one should come first, A1 or A2?

Comment: Assuming v take the last updated. Taking this case, the order has to be A2, A1 since B4 is the least modified and then comes B2.